# Dynamic SQL WHILE leads to many winodws in result pane in management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have such a query:

```
    declare @ProjectID int
    declare @Keyword nvarchar(255)
    declare @SEID int

    select distinct 
           @ProjectID=Project_Id,
           @Keyword=keyword,
           @SEID=SE_Id 
    from [RL].[SearchMetrics_ProjectKeyword] --it returns 120 rows

    while @ProjectID is not null
    begin
        SELECT * 
        FROM Table 1 
        where ID = @ProjectID 
          and Keyword = @Keyword 
          and SEID = @SEID
    end
```

then I have 120  result windows in result pane. But I would like to have all the resualts only in one window

Comment: `UNION`? `UNION ALL`? and why even you are using a `WHILE` loop?

Comment: I have to use the variable from the first query in the second query

Comment: Just JOIN these tables. Single select.

Comment: Just insert the results inside a temp table, and use the temp as the output

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I would like to use this way not join or temp table. is it possible?

Comment: no, you don't need to use variables. And does your code even work as you intend it?, because assigning values to variables that way gives it just one value

Comment: @Kaja why would you prefer this way when it would have far worse performance?

Comment: As Lamak said the `WHILE` loop doesnt change the @project variable so never end

Comment: The more I look at your code, the more convinced I am that it doesn't work giving you 120 result sets....how I see it, it would never stop

Comment: Total agreement with @Lamak. Perhaps it just gives up on it's 120th iteration, or perhaps you are just guessing at the number of result sets returned and it's just "A lot of result sets". Your code says to perform the `SELECT` statement in the while loop if `@ProjectID is null`. `While` is a loop so it will, once finished with that `SELECT` start over again, but only if `@ProjectID` is not null. Obviously it's not null since there was never a chance for it to be changed, so it runs the `SELECT` again. and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have 120 result windows in result pane

It occurs if you run 120 select statements

> I would like to have all the resualts only in one window

Do it as a normal join:

```
Select * from
(
  select distinct Project_Id, keyword, SE_Id from [RL].[SearchMetrics_ProjectKeyword]
) f
INNER JOIN
Table1 t
ON
  t.ID=F.Project_ID and 
  t.Keyword= f.Keyword and
  t.SEID=f.SE_ID
```

Your query had some syntax errors so I had o guess at eg the name of Table1. This query might need some minor fixing

Comment: I agree about the `INNER JOIN`, but not with the `It occurs because 120 select statements are run`

Comment: @Lamak Oh, this comment `--it returns 120 rows` confuse Caius :)

Comment: @Sami I know....but that comment from op can't be what is really happening if s/he uses the code in the question

Comment: Yeah, I know @Lamak :)

Comment: The complaint was "my ssms results tab fills up with 120 result grids". I said this occurs if you run 120 statements. I don't recall saying the code as posted runs 120 statements. I've adjusted my answer to improve its clarity